# Continuous linear functional and weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, approximation-theory

I have a question about a continuous linear functional.

$T>0$ : fix.

$C([0,T]):=\{w:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}\,;\, w \,{\rm is\,conti.}  \}$

$C_{0}([0,T]):=\{w \in C([0,T]) \,;  \,w(0)=0  \}$

Then $C([0,T]),C_{0}([0,T])$ is Banach space with supremum norm $\|w\|=\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|w(t)|$

Let $\varphi $ is a continuous linear functional on $C_{0}([0,T])$. i.e. $\varphi\in C_{0}([0,T])^{*}$

Can $\varphi$ be represent as a limit of functionals of the form  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_{i}w(t_{i})$ ?

Here $\xi_{1},\cdots\xi_{n} \in \mathbb{R},t_{1},\cdots,t_{n} \in [0,1]$

My idea:

By Riesz theorem, $\varphi$ is realized by an integral with respect to an certain finite signed measure on $[0,1]$

i.e. $\varphi(w)=\int_{[0,1]}w(s) \mu (ds)\cdots(1)$

If the right side of the equation $(1)$ is represent as a limit of Riemann sum, I think $\varphi$ is represent as a limit of functionals of the form  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_{i}w(t_{i})$. Is this possible?

Comment: To clarify, "limit" here is meant in the sense of weak-* convergence?  (In the sense of norm convergence, it's not true.)

Comment: Sorry. Title was inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\varphi$ can be approximated by such sums.

First of all, $\varphi(f)=\int_{[0,1]}f\,d\mu,$ where $\mu\in\mathscr M[0,1]$ - the set of signed or complex Borel measures on $[0,1]$.

Next, let $n\in\mathbb N$, $\,P=\Big\{t_k=\frac{k}{n}: k=0,1,\ldots,n\Big\}$, and
$$
w_k=\mu\big((t_{k-1},t_k]\big),\,\, k=1,\ldots,n.
$$
Then
$$
\varphi(f)-\sum_{k=1}^n f(t_k)w_k=\varphi(f)-\varphi_n(f)=\sum_{k=1}^n
\int_{(t_{k-1},t_k]} \big(f(x)-f(t_k)\big)\,d\mu(x),
$$
and due to the uniform continuity of $f$, then for every $\varepsilon$,
there exists an $n$ sufficiently large, such that
$$
\lvert \varphi(f)-\varphi_n(f)\rvert \le\varepsilon \|\mu\|.
$$
This shows that $\varphi_n\to\varphi$, weakly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thanks to you, I understand.